# How to access "additional sections" in vim-airline?

Tags: statusline, plugin-airline

The vim-airline documentation addresses statusline sections as "airline_section_[a-z]" and mentions "additional sections" ([...]).  I have searched in vain to figure out what letter/number could be used to address these sections (to make them empty or just change their contents).  Tried capital letters in vain.  Any hints?

Comment: Are you sure, you have read the [documentation](https://github.com/vim-airline/vim-airline/blob/master/doc/airline.txt#L313-L336)?

Comment: Thanks, @ChristianBrabandt  This is what I referred to and what came around in all searches I did: [link](https://github.com/vim-airline/vim-airline)

Comment: and what exactly is your questions? The sections have the name as shown in my first links, e.g. g:airline_section_a, g:airline_section_b, ....

Comment: I was looking for the names "airline_section_error" and "airline_section_warning", which do not appear in what I linked.  I thanked you for pointing me to the place where they do appear.